# How to open all the committed files (GIT) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently I have one file by one file, right click, `Open File`. Currently I am using VS Code Version 1.64.2. OS: Window 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `COMMITS` View

- `Right Click` the commit message
- Select Context Menu option **Open Changes** > **Open Files**

Comment: I right click the commit message and `Open Changes > Open Files`

Comment: @Steve I have no clue why I typed `Ctrl+Click`, I have edited the answer